# Docker apache image, store logs in host?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-volume

I use Docker to build an Apache image, and then use docker-compose to run it. I set up Apache access.log and error.log and want to store them outside of the container. currently, I use Volumes but it stores the data both in container and host.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: apache
    build: .
    container_name: my-image
    volumes:
        - "/var/log/my-app:/var/log/apache2"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
```

My question is how to only store apache log data in a host, and It woule be better if there is a way to stream apache log data to stdout so that I don't need to store in the host.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Volumes but it stores the data both in container and host.

Not really, it should only store data in the host (and makes it visible in the container [through a bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/))

> if there is a way to stream apache log data to stdout

Possible yes, [through configuration](https://serverfault.com/a/768099/783), but that would not be persistent.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood the volume, I thought it stores data in the container because I can see those files in the container.  you help me make it clear, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post for the Apache configuration:

https://serverfault.com/questions/711168/writing-apache2-logs-to-stdout-stderr

Then you can inspect your logs with

```
docker logs <container>
```