# Docker configuration virtual domain name is wrong, can not access

Tags: php, apache, docker

Apache and PHP are installed in the docker image. How to configure the virtual domain name of this machine, you can access curl www.test.com. I have configured the hosts file and httpd.conf, but it is still useless. How do I configure it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some code, otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker apache image, store logs in host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508155/docker-apache-image-store-logs-in-host)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to edit /etc/hosts and add this :

```
127.0.0.1 www.test.com
```

By eg you can do this in your dockerfile :

```
RUN echo "127.0.0.1 www.test.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

(or check your docker configuration if there is any option to do it)